# New Basecamp: ajax or some super new technology?

Tags: ajax, performance, basecamp

We use Basecamp for project management and their new interface is REALLY fast.

This got me interested: looking at its speed and based on some interface clues I concluded that it must be Ajax-based. Then I inspected the site with Chrome and my suspicion was confirmed: indeed the Network pane shows that requests are appended to the page requests and not completely reset as in standard page-to-page navigation.

**But.**

Ajax-based sites are most clearly given away by the fact that they have funky urls:
http://www.example.com/#page1
http://www.example.com/#page2
etc.

Yet in Basecamp it seems that the navigation is standard. Like this:
https://basecamp.com/accountid/project1
https://basecamp.com/accountid/project2

So which is it? Is the new Basecamp ajax-based or is it some new hybrid that I am not aware of? Is this a webserver set-up solution? Is this a programming language (maybe a Ruby) specialty?

Hope someone else is as excited about this as I am :) Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These two recent blog posts by 37signals discuss how they got that "snap" into the new Basecamp:

[How Basecamp Next got to be so damn fast without using much client-side UI](http://37signals.com/svn/posts/3112-how-basecamp-next-got-to-be-so-damn-fast-without-using-much-client-side-ui)

[How key-based cache expiration works](http://37signals.com/svn/posts/3113-how-key-based-cache-expiration-works)

Comment: In regards to your URL question, in newer browsers JavaScript can manupulate the URL bar using "PushState"